# How to prevent "mail merge" warning to appear when opening an OLEObject word document from inside an Excel File

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I've created an excel workbook that contain two word letter and created a VBA script that automatically mail-merge said letter using data inside the workbook itself.

However when i open the letters using "OLEObject.Activate" I encounter two problems :

1. The document systematically show a "mail-merge" warning
2. Said warning is systematically put in background forcing you to do an "Alt+Tab" to find it.

I've tried two methods to open the document :

```
Dim WDApp As Word.Application
Dim WDDoc As Word.Document

WDObject.Activate

Set WDApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
WDAPP.Visible = True
WDApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
Set WDDoc = WDApp.ActiveDocument
```

and :

```
Dim WDApp,WDOpen As Word.Application
Dim WDDoc As Word.Document

'for some reason if I try to create the application directly with WDApp it then won't be able to recognize the active document so I have to open word using a proxy
Set WDOpen = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WDOpen.Visible = True
WDOpen.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

Set WDApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

WDObject.Activate

Set WDDoc = WDApp.ActiveDocument
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to not embed mailmerge main documents in your workbook. Save them outside Excel as ordinary documents before embedding them. This also means your VBA code will need to include the relevant SQL query code.

Answer (score 0):

So I followed macropod recomendation and here the end result :

```
Private Sub Publipost(WDObject As OLEObject, filter As String)
    Dim WDApp As Word.Application
    Dim WDDoc As Word.Document
    Dim excelFileName, connection As String
            
    excelFileName = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Application.ThisWorkbook.Name
    connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=""" & excelFileName & """;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine T"
          
    WDObject.Activate        
    Set WDApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")    
    Set WDDoc = WDApp.ActiveDocument

    With WDDoc.MailMerge
        .OpenDataSource Name:=excelFileName, _
         ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, _
         AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", _
         WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
         Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, connection:=connection, _
         SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Publipostage$`  where TYPEETAB = '" & filter & "' ", _
         SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .Execute
     End With

     WDDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

It's not perfect since if end-user make the error of saving model with mail-merge on, the problem will reappear, but at least it works as long as you don't touch the model.